# Undefined reference to superclass method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to create a function that outputs the data from a binary search tree by means of calling another function from the entry superclass but I keep getting the error:

undefined reference to `Entry::inOrderPrint(Entry*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've tried renaming the superclass inOrderPrint function but to no avail.

The header file for the superclass looks like this:

```cpp
class Entry
{
public:
    //...
    void inOrderPrint(Entry *startNode);

private:
    //...
};
```

The .cpp file for the Entry class:

```cpp
#include "Entry.h"

//...
void inOrderPrint(Entry *startNode)
{
    // printing algorithm
}
```

The subclass BST.h file:

```cpp
#include "Entry.h"

class BST : public Entry
{
public:
    //...
    void inOrderPrint();

private:
    Entry *root;
};
```

And the subclass .cpp file:

```cpp
#include "BST.h"

//...
void BST::inOrderPrint()
{
    Node::inOrderPrint(root);
}
```

Really don't understand why the compiler thinks reference to Entry::inOrderPrint(Entry*) is undefined. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Groovy. There is still something missing though because [if I do this](https://ideone.com/caajTU), the program links. Can I assume `void inOrderPrint(Entry *startNode)` is actually implemented in a cpp file somewhere else?

Comment: @user4581301 yes, the Entry superclass and the BST class are implemented in their own respective .cpp files, I just compressed the code into one .h file so that it would make sense when looking at it on a single page.

Comment: Unfortunately you've oversimplified and eliminated the bug. You're going to have to take a step back, but first be absolutely certain that this cpp file is being compiled and linked.

Comment: @user4581301 as I was fixing up my submission I've actually realized that I simply forgot to set the scope for the inOrderPrintFunction in the Entry.cpp file, which is why the compiler thought that function didn't exist! So thanks for making me fix my post haha

Comment: I love the simple problems. They're easier to solve. That said, a small nag: This is the sort of thing the [mcve] is awesomely effective at solving. Bets if you'd made sure your minimal example reproduced the error, you wouldn't have had to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to add the Entry:: scope to my Entry.cpp file.